# Layered navigation - show stock from two places

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I´m looking for a way to make it possible for our costumers `to have a filter in the layered navigation` for `products in stock in each of our stores`.

It should be something like the following in the layered navigation:

```
Stock status:

Aalborg
Bronderslev
```

then the customer can select the store and should able to see what's in stock.

Don´t know if its possible to solve on the magento layered navigation or there is an extension for that.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'stores' I assume you mean physical locations rather than store views on the same Magento website.

Create an attribute (store_location) and assign the correct values to each product.

In the attribute's Frontend Properties make sure 'Use In Layered Navigation' is set to Yes.

Add the attribute to the relevant attribute set.

Reindex (and flush cache to be on the safe side) and it should appear.

Out of stock items will not appear in the layered navigation (unless back orders enabled and set to 'in stock')